# Index and length must refer to a location within the string. RAD Treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, treeview

I have a telerik RAD Treeview & Listbox.from the server side i need when node clicked & if that node value is 1 then Disable RadListbox.But exception throws like this

> > Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

```
public void DisableListbox()
{
    try
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(treeObj.SelectedValue.Substring(0,1)) == 1)
        {
            RadListBoxProducts.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it means that your code

```
treeObj.SelectedValue.Substring(0,1)
```

is returning you an empty string. Debug your code and place your mouse over

```
treeObj.SelectedValue
```

to see what it is returning.

To avoid exception you can first check that it is returning you a string of atleast length 1

```
if(treeObj.SelectedValue.Length > 1)  //assuming that SelectedValue is returning you string
{
    //your code
}
```